# Meteor showing Accounts.createUser errors

Tags: meteor

I have the following code in my Meteor app where I create new users, assign them 'basic' role. Yet I am having a trouble showing on the client side errors returned while processing Accounts.createUser, can someone please tell me how I can return errors returned by Accounts.createUser while having it on the server as my code below. Thanks

/server/users.js

```
          Meteor.methods({
            'createMemberAccount': function (data, role) {    
              var userId;

              Meteor.call('createNewAccount', data, function(err, result) {
                  if (err) {
                    return err;
                  }
                  console.log('New account id: '+ result);

                  Roles.addUsersToRoles(result, role);
                  return userId = result;
              });

              return userId;
            },
            'createNewAccount': function (adminData) {
                return Accounts.createUser({email: adminData.email, password : adminData.password, roles: adminData.roles});
            }
          });
```

/client/signup.js

```
        Template.signupForm.events({

          'submit #signup-form': function(e, t){
            e.preventDefault();

            var userData = {};
            userData.email = $(e.target).find('[name=email]').val();
            userData.password = $(e.target).find('[name=password]').val();
            userData.roles = ['basic'];

              Meteor.call('createMemberAccount', userData, 'basic', function(err, userId) {
                  if (!err) {
                    console.log('All OK');
                  } else {
                    console.log('Error: ' + err.message);
                  }
                });
            return false;
          }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since You are creating an static rol `"basic"`, you don't need to do that pair of `methods`, and `Meteor.calls`, instead you can use

So, use the `v` on the client side, just like this.

```
Template.register.events({
    'submit #register-form' : function(e, t) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var email = t.find('#account-email').value
        , password = t.find('#account-password').value;

        // Trim and validate the input

      Accounts.createUser({email: email, password : password}, function(err){
          if (err) {
            // Inform the user that account creation failed
          } else {
            // Success. Account has been created and the user
            // has logged in successfully. 
          }

        });

      return false;
    }
  });
```

If you see there is not any role yet incude, so now on the server.js use the [onCreateUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser) method.

```
//Server.js
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  if (options.profile)
    user.profile = options.profile;
    user.role = "basic"
  return user;
});
```

Now thats is more easy, and with less code, if you are trying to create 2 differents roles like `"Admin"` and `"Basic"`, just on the client side create a profile field named "profile.roles" and do a if statement on the `onCreateUser`.

Comment: Thanks Ethaan, your approach exclude the Roles package which I am currently using in the app. Please note that I have Basic, Admin and the possibility to have more roles and group of roles / users in the future that's why I am using the Roles package. Is there anyway I can continue using the Roles and still get specifically what type of errors returned when creating new account? Thanks

Comment: On this example im just not using `addUserToRole` but we are using the `role` field, since you have in mind create differentes roles you maybe need something [like this](http://tesisethan.meteor.com/registrar-cuenta). here is the [code for this](https://github.com/Ethaan/UTTProject/tree/master/client/views/registrar)

Comment: Thank you so much Ethaan your code solved it for me in a blink :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
return Accounts.createUser({email: adminData.email, password : adminData.password, roles: adminData.roles});
```

This part returns the userId once it is created, it doesn't return any errors when it fails.

When it fails, the returned value will be undefined

Also, in the server, we cannot use callbacks with Accounts.createUser
If you want find the errors, you have to use Accounts.createUser in client side.

Answer (score 0):

Coming to this late, but on the server side, you can assign the createUser to a variable and it will return the new user’s _id; then you can check if that exists. For example (server side only):

```
let email = 'foo@bar.com';
let password = 'bar';
let profile = {firstName: 'foo', lastName: 'bar'};
let newId = Accounts.createUser({
    password: password,
    email: email,
    profile: profile
});
if (!newId) {
    // New _id did not get created, reason is likely EMail Already Exists
    throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Cannot create user: " + error.reason);
}
else {
    // Stuff here to do after creating the user
}
```

The Meteor.Error line will be passed back as an error in the callback on the client side, so you can reflect that error to the browser.